# In StoreKit2, is there a way to add appAccountToken when redeeming offer codes?

Tags: ios, swift, app-store, storekit, storekit2

For purchasing a product in StoreKit 2, Apple has the below API with appAccountToken

```
let userId = UUID()
Product.purchase(options: [.appAccountToken(userId)])
```

However there seems no way to feed in an appAccountToken to associate app users with Apple ID users when redeeming offer codes.

In Apple documentation, the below is for presenting a redeem code sheet.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/appstore/3954431-presentoffercoderedeemsheet

```
if let windowScene = await UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene {
  try await StoreKit.AppStore.presentOfferCodeRedeemSheet(in: windowScene)
}
```

The above API does not accept appAccountToken. Did I missing anything or there is no way to do it?

Thanks in advance!